# How to scroll jQueryUI sortable list on touch screen

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html-lists, jquery-ui-sortable

I have jQueryUI sortable list on my page. I also added jQuery UI Touch Punch for touch support. Sortable works fine, but question is how to scroll this list on touch screen? When I touching list item sorting starts and I am able to scroll only if I will touch exactly between list elements.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I face the same problem.

Comment: Hi, @Dysprosium! I added move icon to each list element and added "handle" property to "sortable". So now I can move list items only by click\touch on my move icon.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Our interface doesn't really allow for handles (draggable elements are too small already on mobile) but good to know how you fixed it. :)